# loop through specific sub folders inside a folder and delete files contains specific name - AIX

Tags: bash, shell, aix

My folder structure is as follows:
there are 100 folders and every folder has 3 sub folders (imagine A, B and C). My task is to delete files which has specific text inside folder C only, from all the 100 folders.

i have minimal knowledge on Unix commands and my task is to perform on AIX server
i tried to google around and found the script below (it actually doesn't do the deletion).
and when i tried to execute the following script , i get the following error 
"test.sh[5]: accepted:  not found."
but there is actually "accepted" folder existed.not sure why the error is occurred.

```
for dir in $(ls)
do 
    for dir2 in $(ls)
        do
        cd accepted
        echo $(ls)
        done    
done
```

Could any one help me update the script to perform "loop through sub folders inside a folder and delete files contains specific text inside specific sub folder only" ?

Comment: What do you mean by `specific text`? A filename or a line/word in the text file? In addition what do you mean by `folder C only`? Is the specificity defined locally among folder A, B and C or globally across the 100 folders?
It is highly appreciated if you can describe with an example.

Comment: `rm */c/*accepted*`

Comment: folder structure is as follows 
root folder : X
subfolders inside X are : A, B, C
subfolders inside each folders A, B and C are: D, E, F 
i want to delete file which has specific text in its file name from inside sub folder F only from all the folders A, B and C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me assume the directory tree as an example:

```
X
├── A
│   ├── D
│   │   ├── bar.txt
│   │   └── foo.txt
│   ├── E
│   │   ├── bar.txt
│   │   └── foo.txt
│   └── F
│       ├── bar.txt
│       └── foo.txt
├── B
│   ├── D
│   │   ├── bar.txt
│   │   └── foo.txt
│   ├── E
│   │   ├── bar.txt
│   │   └── foo.txt
│   └── F
│       ├── bar.txt
│       └── foo.txt
└── C
    ├── D
    │   ├── bar.txt
    │   └── foo.txt
    ├── E
    │   ├── bar.txt
    │   └── foo.txt
    └── F
        ├── bar.txt
        └── foo.txt
```

And suppose you want to remove files which starts with `foo` from the directory `F` only.
Then please try the following:

```
find X/*/F -type f -name "foo*" -delete
```

Now the directory tree will look like:

```
X
├── A
│   ├── D
│   │   ├── bar.txt
│   │   └── foo.txt
│   ├── E
│   │   ├── bar.txt
│   │   └── foo.txt
│   └── F
│       └── bar.txt
├── B
│   ├── D
│   │   ├── bar.txt
│   │   └── foo.txt
│   ├── E
│   │   ├── bar.txt
│   │   └── foo.txt
│   └── F
│       └── bar.txt
└── C
    ├── D
    │   ├── bar.txt
    │   └── foo.txt
    ├── E
    │   ├── bar.txt
    │   └── foo.txt
    └── F
        └── bar.txt
```

I hope this meets your requirement.

Comment: Or: `rm X/*/F/foo*`

Comment: @Sumathiputra thank you for the feedback. I'm interested in the modification.

Comment: Thanks. Then you may have replaced it with `-exec rm {}` or something like that. Understood, although I'm not sure why `-delete` does not work.

Answer (score 0):

While possible to implement the logic for identifying the files using tree search, this is not required for this case. Consider the following.

Note that solution will NOT work if any file names have special characters (spaces, quotes, new lines). It will work for "normal" file names (With the characters `a-zA-Z0-9_-.` etc)..

```
file_list=$(grep -l SomeText */C/*)
rm $file_list
```

Possible to combine into one line - use with care

```
rm $(grep -l SomeText */C/*)
```

You can also use `rm -i` instead of `rm` to get prompted for each file to be removed, if needed.